# Committed memory on my tomcat server

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat6, solr, java, outofmemoryerror

I have a problem to configure JVM on my server. The server is a machine runs on AWS with 8G of RAM and 8 CPU. There is only tomcat6 with solr on the server.

Actually I have configured JVM like that:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -D64 -server -Xms4096M -Xmx4096M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

But when the traffic grow up too much I get errors. I guess the problem comes from the `commited memory` But I don't understand why more than 4G of memory is reserved.

[image: memory usage]

If somebody can help me to configure correctly my JVM and tell me why this problem happens.